# Hyperbolic inversions are transitive on unit vectors at $x \in D$

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, inversive-geometry

Consider the Poincaré model in which the hyperbolic plane is the interior of a disk $D$, and a point $x$ in it with two vectors $v$ and $w$ of the same length attached. The reflection with respect to any circle $C$ passing through $x$ fixes $x$ and is orthogonal (it maps the normal and tangent vectors to $C$ at $x$ to themselves respectively). But how can I find a circle such that the reflection with respect to it will take $v$ to $w$?

Comment: When you write "inversion of a circle", are you thinking of hyperbolic reflections, i.e., referring to a circle that represents a hyperbolic line through $x$, and "inversion" is Euclidean inversion? If so, the answer is "yes", but a proof must be tailored to what you're willing to grant about the hyperbolic isometry group. Or is your question computational (how to find the circle $C$, given specific $x$, $v$, and $w$)?

Comment: Hi, @user86418! Thank you for your comment! I would be interested in both kinds of answer. It would be good to know what abstract argument you can use to show that such a circle C exists, and also how to find it. I know a couple of facts about the hyperbolic isometry group, but I am reviewing everything from the start so I don't want to use more than what I put in my question (namely that the reflection wrt $C$ fixes the points on C and and fixes every circle orthogonal ro tangent to $C$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two sketches (that should at least get you started even if they're not exactly what you're seeking):

1. (Geometric) Let $c$ be a non-zero vector at $x$ that bisects the hyperbolic angle between $v$ and $w$, and let $C$ be the hyperbolic line tangent to $c$ at $x$. Euclidean inversion in $C$ (i.e., hyperbolic reflection across $C$) exchanges $v$ and $w$.
2. (Computational) Pick a hyperbolic isometry $T$ such that $T(x) = 0$ (the center of the Poincaré disk $D$), and put $v' = T_*(v)$ and $w' = T_*(w)$. If $C'$ is the diameter of $D$ bisecting the angle between $v'$ and $w'$, then $C = T^{-1}(C')$, the image of $C'$ under the inverse of $T$, is the hyperbolic line through $x$ bisecting the angle between $v$ and $w$.